# How to prevent SVG background image from scaling?

Tags: css, svg, background-image

I have a SVG background image which scales with browser window when I scale the browser window. How can I prevent the svg background from scaling?

Here is the class:

```
.share-btn-bg {
  background: url("../assets/img/share-bg.svg");
}
```

How can I add css styling to prevent image background from scaling down?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `background-size;` setting to that CSS rule, for example `background-size:auto;` or `background-size: 100px 60px;` or whatever you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can set max-width to image to prevent.

Comment: that's a background-image - there is no max-width possibility for that